# How to convert 32 bit .so file to 64 bit .so file for android

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, native

Recently i got mail from google about adding 64-bit .so file. I have 32-bit .so files in my project. Is it possible to convert them in 64-bit .so file. If yes, then how?

Comment: No. You have to compile the source to 64 bit.

Comment: I don't have any idea, how to compile source to 64 bit. Can you explain something?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to convert a compiled 32 bit binary to 64 bit. You have to re-compile the original source code to a 64 bit binary.

How to do so depends on the program and its build system - and it may not even work as 64 bit, depending on how it was written. A generic answer to "how" cannot really be given, but you should probably start by reading the project's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the code using android toolchain. It is available at here https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to decompile a .so binary into c code:
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4624/how-do-i-reverse-engineer-so-files-found-in-android-apks

It might be possible to re-compile it as a 64bit .so